# Differences in rendered color for text with small font-sizes (16px) in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: color, browser, chrome

I have a text with the following color and font-size:

```
color: rgb(60,128,124);
font-size: 16px;
```

But they look completely different on when rendered by Chrome (when compared to what I get on Adobe XD and Firefox). The Firefox render is much more similar to Adobe XD. And Adobe XD is exactly what my designer intended.

[image]
[image]

Look how the "i" on Chrome is basically gray tones. Look how the Adobe XD version renders basically green tones, making a much more vivid color.

**Note1:** If I make the `font-size` larger and larger, these differences tend go away. And they all look the same.

**Note2:** What is even weirder is that **the print above from the Adobe XD was taken on the very same Chrome, using the "Share for development" link.** It's not a print from the Adobe XD desktop software. Even though it was rendered on Chrome, somehow, the render result looks completely different.

Is there a way to have similar render results on colors for small font-sizes across browsers?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using the following font and this is how I'm adding it to my CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  src: url('/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

Comment: There's no secret every browser uses a different rendering, so they will never output the exact same thing 100%.

Comment: @Lucian thanks! Nothing much to do in this case. Maybe I'm using a color where this difference became more apparent. It was the first time I've noticed a "strong" difference like that.